# Automating Mutation Killing In ClickHouse To Address Ongoing Mutation Issues

Tags: clickhouse

I am currently experiencing recurring issues with mutations in ClickHouse, where I encounter the following error:

```
DB::Exception: Exception happened during execution of mutation 'mutation_XXXXX.txt' with part 'YYYY_MM_DD_XXXXX'. This error maybe retryable or not. In case of unretryable error, mutation can be killed with KILL MUTATION query.
```

**Context**

Current approach: I am manually killing mutations using the below query:

```
KILL MUTATION WHERE mutation_id = 'mutation_***.txt';
```

**Question**

I'm seeking guidance on automating the process of killing mutations to address ongoing mutation issues. Is there a recommended best practice for handling mutations, and are there any specific configurations or strategies that can be implemented to prevent or automatically handle such mutation errors?

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am setting TTL on my clickhouse tables and with each ALTER I am getting this mutation exception. It usually works with re-tries.
I am running this:

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table
    MODIFY TTL time + INTERVAL 28 DAY;
```

Since I have multiple tables so wanted a permanent fix for this issue

Comment: more reasonable is to eliminate the cause of issue, not to invent crutches. What is the real error? Check CH logs.

Comment: In CH logs I can see this recurring statement for all the tables I added TTLto:

**Max size depends not only on available space, but also on settings 'number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_execute_mutation' and 'background_pool_size'
 [ 22157 ] {} <Debug>schema.table(574d3b95-b2f5-): Current max source part size for mutation is 0 but part size 7875. Will not mutate part 20230526_1861_1897_13. Max size depends not only on available space, but also on settings 'number_of_free_entries_in_pool_to_execute_mutation' and 'background_pool_size'**

Comment: and Clickhouse version is?